# Summing in groups of rows

Tags: matlab, sum

I need help making sums in matlab, I have a column with this aspect;

7

2

1

0

5

2

8

7

(...)

And now I want to sum those numbers in groups of 4 rows and get a new matrix with those numbers, for this example I will get a new column with:

10 (7+2+1+0)

22 (5+2+8+7)

(...)

Thx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reshape` allows you to make a 4xn-matrix out of your data. Doing so, you can use `sum`.

```
sum(reshape(x,4,numel(x)/4),1)'
```

Comment: Thank's! Exactly what I want!